# add collection to firestore with kotlin problems

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to understand and use firebasefirestore from android studio with kotlin.

I have been following tutorials from the official docs, and from udemy and youtube. I do the exact same thing as shown, but still my collection is not created in the firestore console.

I want to add a collection to firestore from within android studio with kotlin.

To my understanding all my code is correct, I have internet permission, I have all the dependencies needed in my gradle files.

And my code for adding a collection to firebase is the exact same as given in the official docs.

Still no matter what I do, I can not create a collection from running my app.

I can create a firestore collection from within the firestore console without a problem.
My app runs and execute with out any errors (beside not creating the collection in firestore).

Here is my code

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.example.firestoretest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FireStoreTest">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FireStoreTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle project

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eu.example.firestoretest"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
}
```

Creating a db

```
package eu.example.firestoretest

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

@Composable
fun fireStoreTest(){

    // Create a FirebaseFirestore object
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    
    // Pass data onto the firestore db, it must be of type hashmap
    val user = hashMapOf(
        "first" to "Ada",
        "last" to "Lovelace",
        "born" to 1815
    )

    // add the user data to the collection
    db.collection("users")
        .add(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("FB", "onCreate: ${it.id}")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("FB", "onCreate: ${it}")
        }
}
```

I then call the function fireStoreTest in my main function, but it doesn't work.

Is there someone who could explain in very simple terms what it is I am doing wrong ?

link to logcat
https://github.com/McCt68/logcat/blob/main/firestore_logcat.txt

Comment: Please tell us what is the error

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I dont have any errors. my app execute and runs fine. The only problem is it is not creating a collection in firestore

Comment: You mean `OnFaliureListener` is not executing

Comment: Hmm yes that is quite posibel. I am a beginner so I am not sure about anything. Especially when stuff that is supposed to work, dont work and not giving me any error msg. Its pretty hard to solove for me as i have no clue where to begin, and cant understand why it dont work to begin with

Comment: Is any of the log statements inside `addOnSuccessListener` or `addOnFailureListener` print something in the logcat? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: What are your database rules set to on the Firebase console?

Comment: @AlexMamo It dosent seem that my logcat prints out any of the Listener messages. Also my rules are rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 15);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on user device?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Yes I have tested on emulator I have internet connection. I can google webpages no problem. Also ran the app on 2 different real devices with internet

Comment: I have another project with a tutorial I  followed. Its just very complicated for a beginner since it also uses Dagger hilt, MVVM, and its a lot more complicated to understand what is going on. Anyhow that project works. But the guy who made it, is doing it another way. So its hard for me to copy his methods. I just wanted to make the most simple way, and from there on build as i gain knowledge. I can however see that in that project there are permissions Google APIs Service Agent, but that is missing in my own project. How would i give my own project those permissions ?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have linked my logcat in the original question. I am starting to think there is something about the connection that is not right. I dont understand why though. Since all emulators and real devices i have run the app on are connected to the internet just fine. https://github.com/McCt68/logcat/blob/main/firestore_logcat.txt

Comment: @MichaelChristensen I checked your code, you are adding the data correctly but not to a document reference, which you are logging with {it.id}. Can you try [the code with .add() which is here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Hmm I dont know what to day. but for some reason after I tryed i don't know how many different things. It finnaly works now. I am not even sure what was the problem. I had 3 different projects with firestore ( just for learning) and 1 worked, the other two I could not get to work like this one. But for some reasons I dont understand they all work fine now. I would like to say thanks to everyone here who tryed to help me. It will proberly not be long before I am back with other beginner questions :-)

Comment: I am not sure, but I am already using the .add() in my project the whole time. Not sure if i misunderstand you ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having similar issue where I was not able to add collection on Firestore from Android Studio. What worked for me is setting the rules of Firestore to this :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 5, 3);
    }
  }
}
```